# Обрезка изображений (crop) при помощи onClickListener

Tags: android, изображения

Я пытаюсь добавить  [библиотеку](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/205) для обрезки изображений в своё приложение.
В этой библиотеке я нашел какое-то меню **(res/menu)** с таким кодом:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_select"
    android:title="PICK"
    />
```

Но мне необходимо установить `onClickListener` на отдельную кнопку, которая сможет выбрать изображение из Галереи. Как я могу это сделать? Честно говоря, мало что понимаю в этом коде.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_select) {
        resultView.setImageDrawable(null);
        Crop.pickImage(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        beginCrop(result.getData());
    } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        handleCrop(resultCode, result);
    }
}

private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));

    Crop.of(source, destination).asSquare().start(this);
}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        resultView.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

В общем, необходимо понять, что именно передавать по нажатию кнопки, чтобы работала обрезка изображений:

```
button_choose_guest_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


               // Что необходимо тут?


        }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Код ошибки в logcat:

```
01-17 20:23:24.912  12539-12539/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myfirstapp, PID: 12539
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.myfirstapp/com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity}:     java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to     com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageView
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageView
                at com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity.setupViews(CropImageActivity.java:95)
                at com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity.onCreate(CropImageActivity.java:74)    
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
```

Код Активити, в которой находится кнопка для обрезки изображения:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send_guest_photo);
 resultView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_gifts);
button_choose_guest_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                **resultView.setImageDrawable(null);
                Crop.pickImage(SendGuestPhoto.this);**
        }});}}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        beginCrop(result.getData());
    } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        handleCrop(resultCode, result);
    }
}

private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));

    Crop.of(source, destination).asSquare().start(this);
}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        resultView.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Код класса Crop библиотеки: github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/android/crop/Crop.java

Код класса CropImageActivity библиотеки: github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/android/crop/CropImageActivity.java

Сама ошибка

> at com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity.setupViews(CropImageActivity.java:95)
>               at com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity.onCreate(CropImageActivity.java:74)

в logcat ссылается на вот эту строчку из класса CropImageView:

```
imageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.crop_image);
```

Comment: `resultView.setImageDrawable(null);
        Crop.pickImage(ИМЯ_КЛАССА_АКТИВИТИ.this);`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , спасибо за ответ, попробовал Ваш способ. Но, к сожалению, вылазит еще одна непонятная ошибка: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myfirstapplication/com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageView
            Что она означает? В каком направлении искать?

Comment: Это означает, что у вас где-то `ImageView` вместо `CropImageView` и одно к другому не может быть скастовано. Где это и как из приведённого вами кода понять, пожалуй, невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , Юрий, спасибо за помощь! К сожалению, я так и не смог разобраться. Если у Вас есть возможность, посмотрите, пожалуйста, код, приведенный в update моего вопроса, возможно, Вы увидите ошибку. Я, потратив несколько часов, так и не смог понять, как её решить. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: К сожалению у меня нет времени в коде копаться - свой бы написать) Но у меня есть предположение, что вы невнимательно прочитали мануал и либо не тот класс активити используете, либо не ту разметку к ней. Или тип переменной не тот. В вашем вопросе, например, нема объявления `resultView`